# Visual Studio 2015 IDE not working

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 after upgrading Windows 10 and uninstalling Visual Studio 2013, Now some IDE features are not working e.g.

- WPF XAML IDE
- Runtime Text Template
- XML syntax highligh is not working but intelli-list is showing
  [image: T4T Error]
  [image: XML Error]
  [image: XAML Prob]

Comment: What is your question? Why is this so? How to get the previous functionality back?

Comment: Ide for some languages is not working in newer version

Answer (score 0):

Try to run below in command prompt:

devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates